# Proxy webpack-dev-server based on request payload to return json file

Tags: json, mocking, webpack-dev-server, endpoint

So I've searched and I think a saw the entire internet but no solution regarding the issue I encounter.

I have multiple http request which I want to mock. All request have the same url but deviate based on the requestPayload which contain a graphQl query. Based on this query I want to return a specific json file. All proxy settings I have found can handle parameters but do not handle responses based on requestPayload.

Comment: have you found any solution?

Comment: unfortunately, no I haven't

Answer (score 3):

Have you taken a look over this functionality?

https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserver-before

as far as webpack-dev-server is an instance of express app you are able to setup it in the before/after hooks. Hooks get app (server) instance as a first argument.

so for your case your webpack development config would look like:

```
module.exports = {
  //...
  devServer: {
    before: function(app) {
      var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
      app.use(bodyParser.json());

      app.get('/some/path/graphql', function(req, res) {
        var query = req.body;
        // ...your custom logic of 
        // specific query handling goes here

        if (condition(query)) {
           res.json({ mockedResponse: 'foo' });
        } else {
           res.json({ mockedResponse: 'bar' });
        }
      });
    }
  }
};
```

UPD: keep in mind if you're using proxy config for devServer you might want to use `after` hook instead of `before` to let your requests be proxified if needed.